# Counting the number of occurrences of text in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I was tasked to use pandas to check the number of occurrence of a text appearing in my csv file. However i am very confused with pandas library and would appreciate if someone can help me out.

//Example

```
//title row [ round 1, round 2, round 3]

//row 1 [ 1, 2, 0]

//row 2 [ 2, 2, 0]

//row 3 [ 0, 1, 1]
```

So i need to have an output of

Number of occurrence of :

```
0 = 3
1 = 2
2 = 3
```

Any idea how i can do it?

Comment: .value_counts() method should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

`value_counts` calculates this result on a Series. You need first to get that Series by stacking all the columns into one:

```
df.stack()
Out[14]: 
0  round1     1
    round2    2
    round3    0
1  round1     2
    round2    2
    round3    0
2  round1     0
    round2    1
    round3    1
dtype: int64

df.stack().value_counts()
Out[15]: 
2    3
1    3
0    3
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Import the .csv file with [pandas.read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html). Then, you can loop over the columns with [pandas.value_counts](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html)